# iFrame height based on fixed footer with background-size cover

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have some content that is in an iFrame and a Footer that I want to be fixed, but I want the size of the footer to change based upon the user's screen size and I want the footer graphic to fill the footer. The footer has a background image that uses background-size: cover.  So when the user has a wide screen, the footer should be as wide as the screen and the height should maintain the aspect ratio of the background image.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <iframe id="xyz">
  </iframe>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div id="innerFooter">
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like:

```
#content {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #6AA3D4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
}
.innerFooter {

    background: url("images/footerMain.png");

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I want my footer to be at the bottom of the page and to resize appropriately (height/width) to fully fit the background graphic.
I also want my main content (iframe) to be the full height of the page to the top of the footer.

Right now my iframe is not the full height of the page.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `position:absolute` to footer use `position:fixed` and height should be in pixel for footer not in %.

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px; /*changed percent to pixel*/
    background-color: #fff;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed; /*changed absolute to fixed*/
    width: 100vw;
}
```

see more on CSS positioning: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I will used fixed. For my footer height, I don't really know what it will be. I am relying on the background-size:cover of the innerFooter. That is why i did percent. Since the height should vary depending on the user's window width, how can I handle that height.

Comment: You can set footer height as per your need  in pixels and minus that footer height from iframe height height: calc(100% - 60px);